# when text gets long it alters the form I have, also having hard time fitting divs in the right places

Tags: html, css, django

I'm having a very hard time trying to solve this. I got a back-end working but problem is html and css. I'm trying to make it like this here; [image]

picture on the far left, user name on top and text below the user name and next to picture which is also the style youtube use. Here's my try.[image]

as you can see when text isn't too long it kinda works but when it gets big it alters the form. Also as for the reply comment, the whole thing is a mess. I moved things around but still won't do the job. 
Here's my full code(I'm using django template language here as well) and you can see simplified version here https://jsfiddle.net/n9h7gy54/ (it might be better to see the one here because my full code is very messy)

```
<table class='table'>

{% for comment in comments %}
<tr>
  <td>
  <div class="wholeComment" style="width:100%; margin:auto; font-size:14px;">
    <div class="profileImage" style="float:left;">
    <a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' comment.user.user %}"><img src="{{ comment.user.get_mugshot_url }}" height='48' width='48' /></a>
    </div>
  <div class="comment_header" style="float:left;">
    <div class="commentInfo">
    <a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' comment.user.user %}" style="padding:5px;">{{ comment.user.user }}</a>| <small>{{ comment.timestamp|timesince }}  </small>
    </div>
    <div class="aboutComment">
    <span style="margin:5px; word-break: break-all;">
    {{ comment.get_comment }}</span> 
    </div>
  <div class="comment_bottom" style="padding:3px;">
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<div class="make_reply">
    <a href='#' class='reply_btn'>reply</a>
        <div class='reply_comment'>
        <form method="POST" action='{% url "comment_create" %}'>{% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' name='post_id' id='post_id' value='{% url "comment_create" %}'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='origin_path' id='origin_path' value='{{ comment.get_origin }}'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' id='parent_id' value='{{ comment.id }}' />
        {% crispy comment_form comment_form.helper %}

        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
    <div class="replyInfo">
    {% if not comment.is_child %}
        <div class="wholeReply">
          {% if comment.comment_count %}
        <a href='#' class='replies'>           
         view{{comment.comment_count}}reply</a>
          {% endif %}
        <div class="got_replies">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        {% for child in comment.get_children %}
<hr>        
        <li>
        <div style="float:left;">
        <a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' child.user.user %}" style="float:left;"><img src="{{ child.user.get_mugshot_url }}" height='48' width='48'/></a><a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' child.user.user %}" style="float:left;">&nbsp; {{ child.user.user }}</a>
      </div>
    <div style="word-break: break-all; ">
    {{ child.get_comment }}</div> 
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
        {% endif %}


</td></tr>

{% endfor %}

</table>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap or any ui library at all or just raw css?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap col-sm-9 and col-sm-3 for the above pic

Comment: Were you looking  for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/n5tmn4ob/1/) then?..

Comment: @Sayse thank you for that but actually I am trying to put {{comment.user}} and date next to the picture. your source helps me alot,,,still I'm not quite getting it the way i want it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <img src="{{ comment.user.get_mugshot_url }}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">     
                 <p>
                   {{ comment.user.user }}
                 </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <small>{{ comment.timestamp|timesince }} </small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <span>{{ comment.get_comment }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% for child in comment.get_children %}
        {% include 'commentrow.html' comment=child %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

You can save this snippet as a template called `commentrow.html` and it will work recursively for children, including it in your template the same way

```
{% for comment in comments %}
{% include 'commentrow.html' comment=comment %}
{% endfor %}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5tmn4ob/2/)

The important part is the `col-xs` tags, since this will mean the columns don't wrap regardless of screensize.

Comment: ok thanks I'll read this through,  i'm trying to put {{ comment.timestamp|timesince }} below { comment.user.user }}| but next to the image. And same for the reply one. My fault for not being able to put these into  words ;)

Comment: @emfour - Oh that should be simple enough, just make it a new row, I'll update my answer